# Node js right way to code (scope)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new in js. In my project I'm using mysql and node js.
Somewhere in controller I need to get some data from differnet models. In php it looks like

```
function some() {
    $user = $user->getOne($id); 
    $photos = $photos->getOne($user->id);
    $posts  = $post($user->id, $photo->uid)
}
```

and I have all this variables in one scope
in node js result of model is async, so it's look like nestings callbacks.
Short example

```js
UserModel.findbyid(result.user_id, function (err, user_data) {
  PhotoModel.GetVoteCount(user_data.id, result.id, function (res_count) {
    PhotoModel.getWinners(function (err, winners_ar) {
      PhotoModel.getweekusers(1, function (result_week) {
        response.render('one.twig', {
          view_user: request.user,
          image: result,
          p_user: user_data,
          count: res_count,
          winners: winners_ar,
          week_users: result_week['photos']
        });
      });
    })
  });
});
```

so I have nested callbacks, I feel it's not right way to code, can you explain best practices?

Comment: `write` or `right`?

Comment: This is the right way of coding in JavaScript :) You can check this blog post for example http://www.joshwright.com/tips/javascript-christmas-trees-promises-and-event-emitters, and if you Google `Christmas Trees of Doom JavaScript`, you'll find some good article that will explain why this is, and how to get use to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

This simplifies what you call "callback hell" through some functions that helps create flows in async code.

Specifically to your case - [async.waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :

1. Use async module ([async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async))
2. Use a library which returns promises (like [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql)).

Answer (score 0):

Use  promises,or libraries that will help you use promises.